# Define route in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I defined the a new route (see below). When I launch the application, I'd like by default:

- Go Home/Index
- If I go to /Customer/Detail/MyCode get "MyCode"

When I use this configuration, I start on Home/Index it's ok but /Customer/Detail/MyCode give a null value all the time.

If I inverse the routes.MapRoute, I have :

- By default I go  to /Customer/Detail and I get mycode value all the time (no null anymoe)
- I don't start on /Home/Index

Any idea ?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "CustomerDetail",
    "{controller}/{action}/{code}",
    new { controller = "Customer", action = "Detail", code = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single route will be enough:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{code}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", code = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

When you request `Home/Index` this will invoke the `Index` action on `HomeController` and pass null as the `code` parameter and when you request `Customer/Detail/MyCode` the `Detail` action will be invoked on `CustomerController` and passed `code=MyCode`.

The reason you were getting null is that both your routes are equivalent, meaning that they are of the form `Controller/Action/SomeCode` which means that for both urls the first route is matched, but the parameter is called `id` instead of `code` so you are getting `code=null`. Another possibility is to simply leave the default route as is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

and then rename the parameter to the `Detail` action to id:

```
public ActionResut Detail(string id)
{
    // if you request Customer/Detail/MyCode the id parameter will equal MyCode
}
```

Comment: Home/Index won't be receive a value that's means I'll go to /Customer/Detail/MyCode ... I don't want that. I start the application and I have to stay /Home/Index. Later, I will have something like /Product/Detail/MyCode Keep id is not relevant, it's not an id it's a code ..